# Realm ? curious log 'mThreadGroupCpuId 3 mRenderThreadCpuId 3 affinity'

Tags: android, realm

I have this message that I see repeting itself over and over in my logs :

```
                     D  mThreadGroupCpuId 3 mRenderThreadCpuId 3 affinity
                     D  mThreadGroupCpuId 3 mRenderThreadCpuId 3 affinity
                     D  mThreadGroupCpuId 3 mRenderThreadCpuId 3 affinity
                     D  mThreadGroupCpuId 3 mRenderThreadCpuId 3 affinity
                     D  mThreadGroupCpuId 3 mRenderThreadCpuId 3 affinity
                     D  mThreadGroupCpuId 3 mRenderThreadCpuId 3 affinity
                     D  mThreadGroupCpuId 3 mRenderThreadCpuId 3 affinity
                     D  mThreadGroupCpuId 3 mRenderThreadCpuId 2 affinity
                     D  mThreadGroupCpuId 3 mRenderThreadCpuId 2 affinity
```

It seems to happend only in a specific activity where I'm doing my Realm experimentations. Does someone know what does it stand for ? Is it normal or should I worry about anything ?

StackOverflow is preventing me from posting this message with this few explanations but I just don't know what to add. Please ask me if I forgot anything.

---

My Realm versions :

```
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

and

```
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'
```

---

Thanks,

Comment: You might have forgotten your "Realm experimentations". And Realm version.

Comment: I don't know what to show about them, it's a complex set of activity fragments and presenters. Do you know what this message means ? for me to narrow down where it could come from ? I add my realm conf

Comment: Do you run anything on a render thread?

Comment: Didn't know renderthreads before you mentioned it but it seems related with animated views. I'm using à lib to display charts, I'll look into it, that might be its fault and not realm's

Comment: I changed my graph lib to MPAndroidChart, the message is still here, I don't know what else could use a `RenderThread`.

Comment: Can you create a small sample app which reproduce the issue?

Comment: Are we sure that's even an issue ? I'll try to but it could take me à while